# Windows XP SP3 User profile restoration

Tags: windows-xp, domain, user-profiles

I messed around by accident with the computer and I am a new IT intern.

1. I restored my system as I had lost everything stored in my profile.
2. A new profile 'mlinda" is created with a proper domain attached to it
3. My old profile "m.linda" remains and the domain is of a local computer and it no longer works with the (eg. CAA MAU) server's domain
4. The original "m.linda" user profile contains almost nothing in it
5. the newly restored user profile "mlinda" has fully restored.

Question:

1. How do I change "mlinda" (that has successfully retored everthing) back to 
   "m.linda"
2. How do I safely delete the new "mlinda" and ensure everything is back to normal with the old profile name?
3. The outlook email is `m.linda@xyz.com`. Will this be affected in anyway by changing the newly restored profile name back its old name?
4. Do I have to change anything in the registry value?
5. Should I do it with Administrator account in normal mode or safe mode?
6. Can someone show me in video or picture attachment or just explain step by step, please?

Any help is appreciated as I need to fix it by tomorrow or I lose my job.

Answer (score 1):

If you log on as an administrator your should be able to copy the "good" profile to the "bad" profile

Right click My Computer, Properties then the Advanced Tab. Click on Settings under User Profile section.

Click on the profile you wish to copy and click Copy To:  You then browse to the folder with the "bad" profile and copy.  You will be warned about over-writing the  folder.

There is a nice [tutorial](http://www.petri.co.il/copy_user_profiles_in_windows_xp.htm) on Petri as well.

Comment: Thank you dave. some forums mentioned about possibility of losing emails from outlook and will it retain the domain settings (since the new profile has the correct one)? wouldn't it be easier to delete the old account and rename the new back to it's old name? could it be as simple as that?